# JMeter AMQP Publisher (Sampler)

Tags: jmeter, amqp

I am using an AMQP Publisher Sampler within my JMeter Test Plan, is there any way to loop and Publish the **Message Content** using a defined time period (i.e. once per second)?

As part of the **Message Content** I am sending a TIMESTAMP that will update through each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Constant Thoughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/), this way you will be able to limit sampler(s) execution rate to the desired one.

The latter can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Throughput Shaping Timer]